# grep/sed : ignore a number

Tags: shell, sed

When I use, for example, the command

```
grep -c "a" output output2 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

the result is `0` for `output` and `20` for `output2` because of its name. I want to ignore that `2` in `output2`'s name. How can I do that, knowing that name can be different, for example `output3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cut everything but the number at the very end.

```
grep -c "a" output output2 | sed 's/^.*:\([0-9]*\)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed`.  For the case that is not working, you should use `tr`.  (eg, replace `sed 's/[^0-9]//g'` with `tr -dc 0-9`, which is nearly identical, but also removes the trailing newline.  This does not solve your problem; I'm merely pointing out that you shouldn't use `sed` to do a job that `tr` is better for.)  To get the second field of colon delimited output, use `cut`:

```
grep -c a output output2 | cut -d: -f2
```